# The Mean of the Resultant Data

Tags: statistics

I was studying for some quizzes when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> The mean of the data set comprising of 16 observations is 16. If one of the observations valued 16 is deleted and three new observations valued 
>   3, 4 and 5 are added to the data, then the mean of the resultant data would  be?

**My work**

I do know that the equation of means $\bar x$ would be $\bar x = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{x_i}{n}$

Then the mean would be $\bar x = 16$, so I got to find the remaining 15 observations that gives the mean of 16. Once I got those 15 observations (and one observation, 16 will finally be included, making it now 16 observations), I can replace one of the observation, valued at 16, by three observations 
3, 4, and 5.

Here's the problem.....I don't know how to get these 15 observations because of scant data available.

How do you get the mean of the resultant data?

Answer (score 0):

Given:
$$\bar{x}=\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{15}+16}{16}=16 \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{15} x_n=16^2-16=240.$$
The number $16$ is removed and the numbers $3,4,5$ are added, then:
$$\bar{x}=\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{15}+3+4+5}{18}=\frac{240+12}{18}=14.$$